# yolov7 ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _fblas: %1 is not a Win32 application

Tags: tensorflow, yolo

When I start the tutorial it shows an error. I am using windows 11 64 bit. I installed all the packages through anaconda, and I can’t understand what the problem could be. (Python 3.9)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iirof\PycharmProjects\rf_detect_mob\yolov7-custom\train.py", line 24, in <module>
    import test  # import test.py to get mAP after each epoch
  File "C:\Users\iirof\PycharmProjects\rf_detect_mob\yolov7-custom\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    from models.experimental import attempt_load
  File "C:\Users\iirof\PycharmProjects\rf_detect_mob\yolov7-custom\models\experimental.py", line 6, in <module>
    from models.common import Conv, DWConv
  File "C:\Users\iirof\PycharmProjects\rf_detect_mob\yolov7-custom\models\common.py", line 17, in <module>
    from utils.plots import color_list, plot_one_box
  File "C:\Users\iirof\PycharmProjects\rf_detect_mob\yolov7-custom\utils\plots.py", line 19, in <module>
    from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt
  File "C:\Users\iirof\anaconda3\envs\rf\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\__init__.py", line 309, in <module>
    from . import _sigtools, windows
  File "C:\Users\iirof\anaconda3\envs\rf\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\windows\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from ._windows import *
  File "C:\Users\iirof\anaconda3\envs\rf\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\windows\_windows.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy import linalg, special, fft as sp_fft
  File "C:\Users\iirof\anaconda3\envs\rf\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 233, in __getattr__
    return _importlib.import_module(f'scipy.{name}')
  File "C:\Users\iirof\anaconda3\envs\rf\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\iirof\anaconda3\envs\rf\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 197, in <module>
    from ._misc import *
  File "C:\Users\iirof\anaconda3\envs\rf\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_misc.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .blas import get_blas_funcs
  File "C:\Users\iirof\anaconda3\envs\rf\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 213, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _fblas: %1 не является приложением Win32.
```

Tried to install different versions of python, but nothing new.

Comment: Please help us to know which code you are trying to implement when this error pops up along with the TensorFlow version you have installed in your system?

Answer (score 0):

From the paths in the OP's traceback it seems like there are some coexisting installations of Python on the system, maybe leftovers from previous installations, or there is a mixing in conda and pip, which should be avoided whenever possible.

You need to delete all the existing traces of python, reinstall it and run this command in your jupyter notebook.

```
 pip install -- pywin32==227
```

This will solve your issue .

The same issue has been discussed in a greater detail [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_core/issues/187) and this github [conversation chain](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1409).